# My applet cannot connect to Servlet and transfering data

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, applet, httpurlconnection

I want to send some data from my Applet to a specific Servlet which supposed to connect to a MySQL database and store the transferred data.
In the Applet side I used this method to transfer data from applet to the servlet:

```
  public void sendData() {
        try {
            URL postURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/MyApplet/mydb");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) postURL.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();

            String param1 = "data1";
            String param2 = "data2";
            String param3 = "data3";

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write("param1=" + URLEncoder.encode(param1, "UTF-8")
                    + "&param2=" + URLEncoder.encode(param2, "UTF-8")
                    + "&param3=" + URLEncoder.encode(param3, "UTF-8"));
            out.flush();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(GameApplet.this, e.getMessage(), "Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Which MyApplet/mydb is the path of my Selrvet.
and in the Servlet side I wrote this code:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        String parameter1 = request.getParameter("param1");
        String parameter2 = request.getParameter("param2");
        String parameter3 = request.getParameter("param3");

        connectToDB();
        insert(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
//        insert("X", "Y", "Z");
        closeDB();
}
```

which `processRequest()` calls from `doGet()` and `doPost()`.
The Servlet works properly when I call it directly from its http link and fill the database without any problem but when I call it from the applet , nothing happens and even without any exception! to be honest , they can't communicate with each other and I'm really confused.

Comment: Try using `URLConnection` as shown in the example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Comment: I tried this but I can't communicate with the Servlet through Applet yet! It seems something is wrong when the Servlet want to receive the data or when Applet want to send, because both class work properly when I test them separately ! :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to send more than one parameter finally:
( it's just a suggestion and maybe there is still a better solution but it worked for me )

> Applet side:

```
    URL helloServletURL = new URL(getCodeBase().toString() + "mydb");
    URLConnection urlConnection = helloServletURL.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

    String param1 = "data1";
    String param2 = "data1";
    String param3 = "data1";

    ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    objOut.writeUTF(param1 + "%" + param2 + "%" + param3);

    objOut.flush();
```

> Servlet side:

```
    ObjectInputStream dataInput = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    String param = dataInput.readUTF();

    dataInput.close();

    String[] values = param.split("%");
```